# admin-on-rest: Unable to scroll horizontally on wide list views

Tags: admin-on-rest

When Admin-on-rest is running on safari mobile (and presumably all small screens) wide views cannot be scrolled horizontally. This is particularly problematic because in List View often the "Edit" link is on the right of a row.

There is no way to pinch-zoom out to expose the missing parts of the page.

This can be reproduced on the demo site: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/

Looks like the culprit is a CSS style using `flex-direction: column`

Removing this style reinstates horizontal scrolling.

[image]

Is this a bug (possibly a cross-browser issue?) or is this limitation necessary for a reason that I'm not aware of?

***Possible solution***: Remove `overflow-x: hidden` on the table container which allows a wide table of results to be scrolled horizontally but keeps the overall page width the same size as the page so buttons/filters/etc are aligned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the datagrid on small screens. See the documentation about this: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Theming.html#responsive-utility

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this way to horizontally scroll in small size devices:

```
export const ReservationList = (props) => (
    <div style={{
        display: "flex",
        flex: "1 1 auto",
        overflowY: "hidden",
        overflowX: "scroll"
    }}>
        <List {...props} title="Reservation List">
            <Datagrid>
              ...  
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a horizontal scrollbar in react-admin list view. Add a div around the Datagrid. maxWidth: "100vw" cuts off the last column, hence 95.

```
<div style={{overflowX: 'auto', maxWidth: "95vw"}}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit" bulkActionButtons={false}>
...
```